# Retrieving model position after applying modeltransforms in XNA

Tags: c#, model, matrix, xna, position

for this method that the goingBeyond XNA tutorial provides, located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203897%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx), It would be really convenient if I could retrieve the new position the model is being drawn, after I apply all the transforms to the mesh. I have edited the method a little for what I need. Does anyone know a way I can do this?

```
    public void DrawModel( Camera camera )
    {
        Matrix scaleY = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(1, 2, 1));
        Matrix temp = Matrix.CreateScale(100f) * scaleY * rotationMatrix * translationMatrix * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.Pi / 6) * translationMatrix2;
        Matrix[] modelTransforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modelTransforms);
        if (camera.getDistanceFromPlayer(position+position1) > 3000) return;
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.World = modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * temp *  worldMatrix;
                effect.View = camera.viewMatrix;
                effect.Projection = camera.projectionMatrix;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can get more answers on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Vector3.Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector3.transform) method to apply matrices to your position vector.

Comment: Did you read the question? That answer was completely useless, and I demonstrated knowledge of what you told me exactly in the source code.
If you read the question, you would see that I need to retrieve the new vector after transformations, not applying the transformations.

Comment: The difference is receiving the updated position, as opposed to setting the new position. Setting the position requires simple matrix applications, but receiving the new position is a bit tougher